# Ansible: Start service in next host after service finished starting on previous host

Tags: ansible

I have three hosts in which I want to start a service in a rolling fashion. The host 2 needs to wait for the service to finish starting on host 1, and host 3 needs to wait for service on the host 2.
Host 1 has finished starting the service when a line with an instruction like:

> Starting listening for CQL clients

is written to a file.

How can I instruct Ansible (`service` module preferably) only to start the following host, when the service on the previous host writes the line to that file?

Comment: Did you have a look at the ansible doc about rolling upgrades ? They talk about it in [advanced features](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html). There are also some [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/guide_rolling_upgrade.html). The key here is the use of `serial` at play level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to serialize at a task level. So I had to build another playbook specific to start the service and used `serial: 1` in the playbook yaml.

My files now look like this:

**roles/start-cluster/tasks/main.yaml**

```
- name: Start Cassandra
  become: yes
  service:
    name: cassandra
    state: started

- name: Wait for node to join cluster
  wait_for:
    search_regex: "Starting listening for CQL clients"
    path: /var/log/cassandra/system.log
```

**start-cluster.yaml**

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
  - start-cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll probably need to break your playbook down a bit, for example

Your restart.yml contents:

```
- service:
    name: foobar
    state: restarted
- wait_for:
    search_regex: "Starting listening for CQL clients"
    path: /tmp/foo
```

and then your main.yml contents:

```
- include_tasks: restart.yml
  with_items:
    - host1
    - host2
    - host3
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html

Comment: For this, to work, I need to hardcode the hosts in the `with_items` list? Any way that I can just use the list from the `hosts` file?

Comment: This doesn't work anyway. It's not possible to serialize at a task level. The restart.yaml is called for all hosts at the same time.

Comment: But the `wait_for` has helped to find the solution, so here's an upvote anyway. :) Thanks!

Comment: good stuff, i totally missed the fact that it will run the tasks for all the hosts in parallel. Maybe this could help execute tasks in serial mode https://serverfault.com/a/967205 ?